# Having trouble writing batch script that mirrors folder to NAS drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I've been looking throughout the forum to find an answer and nothing. I just want to copy files from my desktop folder to my NAS drive. I wrote this script below and I got an error "**You do not have the Manage Auditing user right.*****  You need this to copy auditing information (/COPY:U or /COPYALL)"**
Any ideas why this wouldn't work or what the error means?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET _Source=C:\Users\desktop\folder
SET _dest=\\NASdrive\share\folder
SET _what=/COPYALL
SET _ options=/R:0 /W:0 /MIR /LOG:log.txt
ROBOCOPY %_source% %_dest% %_what% %_options%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might have an explanation - [Robocopy /copyall](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7b139442-e6aa-441f-b1e1-4f473b11223c/robocopy-copyall)

Says:

> This thing with robocopy /copyall is that the first thing it does it change the permissions on the destination folder that you are copying into.

I'm guessing your NAS doesn't appreciate robocopy changing permissions.

COPYALL is equivalent to [/COPY:DATSOU](http://burpee.smccme.edu/studenthowtos/robocopy.htm)

```
/COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
                     (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps).
                     (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info)
```

So you are telling Robocopy to set Attributes, ACLs, Owner, and Auditing Info on the destination drive. Since this is a NAS (and assuming not Windows) I don't think Robocopy can do this.

Comment: Awesome thank you that helped a lot!I removed the COPYALL line and it works fine now. I wonder why I got a -1... I thought that was a decent question

Comment: It wasn't really a programming question and was more of a system administrator question. http://serverfault.com/ might have been a better forum.

Comment: Oh yes that is very correct! Thank you I never saw that site!

Answer (score 3):

You have a space between `_` and `options`. Removing this space made the code work fine for me.